# How to retroactively remove `hg cp source targe` linkage?

Tags: mercurial

I've got a change that has some files that I initially created using `hg cp source target`. However, looking at the diffs for these, the files ended up being so different that keeping the linkage with the source files makes for really hard-to-read diffs.

How can I break that link in my commit before I push this change upstream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discovered a method by experimentation. I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but it seems to work:

```
$ hg uncommit path/to/file
$ hg revert path/to/file
$ hg add path/to/file
$ hg amend
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a more up-to-date answer, you can simply do the following:

```
$ hg forget path/to/file
$ hg add path/to/file
```